# Getting an error when DateTime converted to a string returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have the following code block with in one of my controllers, this code returns two date strings formatted a certain way based on culture for my View to consume.

```
string dateStringForSystem = "";
string dateStringForActiveMetrics = "";
string cultureConfigKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InstanceCulture"];
DateTime? lastEntryDateForSystem = null;
DateTime? lastEntryDateForActiveMetrics = null;
DataSet dSet = DataHelper.Measurements_GetLastMeasurement(userSession.UserIDNative);                

foreach (DataRow dr in dSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    lastEntryDateForSystem = (DateTime?)dr["LastMeasurementWhen"];
    lastEntryDateForActiveMetrics = (DateTime?)dr["LastMeasurementForActiveGoalsWhen"];             
}

// Format viewdata dates based on culture and convert it to string
if (cultureConfigKey == "en" )
{                
    ViewData["DateStringForSystem"] = dateStringForSystem = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", lastEntryDateForSystem);
    ViewData["DateStringForActiveMetrics"] = dateStringForActiveMetrics = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", lastEntryDateForActiveMetrics);
}
else
{
    ViewData["DateStringForSystem"] = dateStringForSystem = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yy}", lastEntryDateForSystem);
    ViewData["DateStringForActiveMetrics"] = dateStringForActiveMetrics = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yy}", lastEntryDateForActiveMetrics);
 }
```

With in the View code I store and use the view data as such. But if the strings return null I'm getting an error.  Is null not returned as a string even when I convert the dateTime to a string?

```
var dateStringForSystem = ViewData["DateStringForSystem"];
var dateStringForActiveMetrics = ViewData["DateStringForActiveMetrics"];

    @if (dateStringForSystem == "")
    {
        // some html
    }
    else if (dateStringForActiveMetrics != "")
    {
       <span>@dateStringForActiveMetrics</span>
    }
```

Still pretty new to C#, so any recommendations on cleaning this code up is also greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting the error in the view or in the code behind?

Comment: FYI: `string.Format()` and `DateTime.ToString()` cannot return null.

Comment: I'm wondering if doing this DateTime? lastEntryDateForSystem = string.IsNullOrEmpty(date);  would solve the problem

Comment: It seems to be in the code behind rather than in the view @JonLaMarr